# Truffle throwing errors that I am using the wrong compiler (but I am not)

Tags: visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, blockchain, solidity, truffle

I am using Truffle to test migrating smart contracts in VS Code.

I am trying to migrate my smart contracts but am getting an error that "***Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.8.10+commit.fc410830.Emscripten.clang)***". The error is telling me this line "***pragma solidity >=0.4.25 <0.7.0;***" exists in two .sol files ***(But it does not!)***.

In both files, I am trying to use solc version 0.8.10 by stating "***pragma solidity >=0.8.0 <0.9.0***". I also know for certain that I am using solc version 0.8.10 as running truffle version shows me that. Any idea what is going on? Am I being dumb and missing something obvious?

I will provide some pictures.

Me declaring the solidity version I would like to us:

[image: screenshot]

The errors that I am getting, these lines do not exist in the files the error suggests they do?

[image: screenshot]

Running truffle version shows the I have set truffle to use my solc 0.8.10 compiler

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/10669875) Instead, copy-paste the text into the question. To format it correctly, see [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)